# Implement bit.ly url shortening in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, json, hyperlink, bit.ly, url-shortener

I'd like to implement bit.ly URL shortening service in my application and from biy.ly's API docs I read It uses JSON to short a link...
Unfortunately, I never used JSON and I don't know where to start.
Can anyone explain me how to implement bit.ly URL shortening service in my application?

Thanks,
Matteo

Comment: I recommend filing away www.jslint.com for testing the correctness of your json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my bitly project at github ... http://github.com/st3fan/iphone-bitly

Comment: How can I return the shortened URL as a string in my action?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is just a (Javascript) way to encode you're data in name value pairs in an http POST request. So you just need to use a good encoder/decoder API for you're iphone application. See also this tutorial:

**[tutorial: Json over http on the Iphone](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)**

Want to know more about how JSON works, this book has an excelent chapter on it:

[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Comment: You don't need JSON for the Bit.ly API.